# Using a method as callback function for a filter affects scope of the callback

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filter

I ran into an issue in angular where my method loses its scope by being called as a callback function. Can someone explain **why `this` changes to `undefined`**?

```
@Component({...})
export class SomeClass {
  public status = 'any';

  public filter_account_accesses() {
    console.log( this.status );
    let account_accesses = [...];
    return account_accesses.filter( this.status_filter )
  }
  private status_filter( account_access ): boolean {
    console.log( typeof this );
    // this is undefined!
    return true;
  }
}
```

PS: I already know I can work around the issue by passing `this` as an argument. I want to know **why** the change of scope is happening. And optionally how I can prevent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value of `this` in a function depends on how that function is called. Let's look at a simple example:

```
function A() {}
A.prototype.foo = function() {
  // do something
}

const a = new A();
```

If `foo` is called like this, the value of this inside will be the `a` object:

```
a.foo();
```

But if you store a reference to the `foo` function to some other variable, it won't be bound to the `a` instance anymore and the value of this will be undefined:

```
const f = a.foo;

f(); // <- value of this inside is undefined
```

This is similar to what you're doing in your code snippet: you're passing a reference to the instance method `status_filter` to the filter function and it's not bound to your instance, that's why when the `filter` callback is called the value of this inside is undefined.

You can bind the function to your instance by using `bind`:

```
return account_accesses.filter( this.status_filter.bind(this) )
```

It will create a copy of your function where `this` points to your instance.

Also, I'm recommending you this great and thorough article about how `this` works in JS: http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-3-this/

Answer (score 0):

Because your function is called with array filter. There is 2 ways to do it without losing `this`:

1. Using arrow function

```js
return account_accesses.filter(value => this.status_filter(value));
```

2. Using `bind`

```js
return account_accesses.filter(this.status_filter.bind(this));
```